# Como pegar o nome das cidades, usando neo4j e PHP?

Tags: php, neo4j

Segui este [tutorial](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/learning-cypher-with-san-francisco-bay-map) para fazer o seguinte:

```
    echo "<h2>Encontre a rota mais curta da cidade A para a cidade B</h2>";

    $query4 = 'MATCH p = (a {name: \'Palo Alto\'})-[r*2..5]->(b {name: \'Santa Clara\'}) WHERE NOT(a-->b) WITH p.name, relationships(p.name) AS rcoll RETURN a.name, b.name, p.name, reduce(totalDistance=0, x IN rcoll| totalDistance + x.distance) AS totalDistance ORDER BY totalDistance LIMIT 5';  

    $result4 = $client->run($query4);

    $record4 = $result4->getRecord();

    echo '<b>' . $record4->get('a.name') . '</b>';

    foreach ($result4->getRecords() as $records4) 
    {
      echo ' ⇢ ' . $records4->get('p.name');
    }

    echo '<b>' . $record4->get('b.name') . '</b>';
```

Tentei o nome das cidades, usando o `p.name` do `MATCH p`.

Semelhante ao `$query4 = 'MATCH (a {name: \'Palo Alto\'})-[r*2..5]->(p) RETURN a.name, p.name LIMIT 5';` que funcionava, só que queria pegar a cidade de Palo Alto à Santa Clara usando a rota mais curta e a distância total porque este resultado deu de Palo Alto para Milpitas por falta de rota mais curta e distância total.

Comment: Talvez eu possa ajudar com a parte do Neo4j e da consulta, porém precisaria que você fosse um pouco mais claro em relação ao seu problema. Eu acredito que não entendi completamente o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: O código `''MATCH p = (a {name: \'Palo Alto\'})-[r*2..5]->(b {name: \'Santa Clara\'}) WHERE NOT(a-->b) WITH p.name, relationships(p.name) AS rcoll RETURN a.name, b.name, p.name, reduce(totalDistance=0, x IN rcoll| totalDistance + x.distance) AS totalDistance ORDER BY totalDistance LIMIT 5''` não funcionou no Neo4j. Mas `MATCH (a {name: \'Palo Alto\'})-[r*2..5]->(p) RETURN a.name, p.name LIMIT 5` funcionou mas pegou as cidades erradas porque usou a rota longa.